# Multi_match and match queries together

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following queries in elastic search :

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "bluefin bat",
      "type": "phrase",
      "fields": [
        "title^5",
        "body.value"
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "body.value": {
        "number_of_fragments": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "title",
    "id"
  ]
}
```

I have tried using "dis_max" but then two of my fields have to be searched for the same query.
The remaining match query has a different query text.

The remaining match query is like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "ingredients": "key1, key2",
      "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I integrate these two queries without using dis_max for joining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer. multi_match internally applies :

```
"dis_max"
```

Hence, you cannot apply `dis_max` with `multi_match`.
But what I could do is I could apply `bool` query to solve this type of problem.

I could apply `should` which actually translates to `OR` boolean value or I could apply `must` which is equivalent to `AND`.

So this is how I modified my query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool":{
      "should": [
        {"multi_match":
          {"query": "SOME_QUERY",
            "type": "phrase", 
            "fields": ["title^5","body"]
          }
        },
        {
          "match":{
            "labels" :{
             "query": "SOME_QUERY",
             "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match":{
            "displayName" :{
             "query": "SOME_QUERY",
             "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": "50%"
    }
    },
  "fields": ["title","id","labels","displayName","username"],
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "body.storage.value": {
        "number_of_fragments": 3}
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps someone in future.